# Found solution to super small font-size on my iPhone, but why?

Tags: css, font-size

My actual iPhone was displaying a super-small font-size for part of my web-site.

I found that the following solved it:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and

```
body {
   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

I do not understand why these work ... any clues?

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: That meta tag makes your website responsive, it changes your width according to the screen size of device. Initial scale means zooming on page load, 1 is normal.

Comment: Doesn’t my css width:100% do the same thing?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: e.g., the vertical scroll bar if there  is one. thanks bunches